# Flux across the surface of a cone

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

My textbook asks the following question:

> Find the flux of $F(x,y,z) = \langle x,y,z \rangle$ across the surface of the cone $ z^2 = x^2 + y^2 $, for $ 0 \leq z \leq 1 $ (normal vectors point upward).

I tried to solve this using both Divergence Thm. and directly. Using Divergence Thm., I got:

> $\iint_S F\cdot n dS = \iiint_E divFdV = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{r} (3)rdzdrd\theta = 2\pi$

However, when performing it directly, I obtained the following:

> $\iint_S F\cdot n dS = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^1 (\langle rcos\theta, rsin\theta, r \rangle \cdot \langle -cos\theta, -sin\theta, 1 \rangle )rdrd\theta = 0 $

There is no solution listed for the problem. Are either of these correct or are neither of them correct?

Comment: How did you arrive at that normal vector for the direct computation?

Comment: I used the formula $ n = \langle -f_x, -f_y, 1 \rangle$ for $ f(x,y) = z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. This gave me $ n = \langle \frac{-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}},\frac{-y^2}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}, 1 \rangle $. Then, since I'm using polar coordinates, I substituted for $ x = rcos\theta$, $y = rsin\theta$, which gave me $n = \langle -cos\theta, -sin\theta, 1 \rangle$.

Comment: $E$ must be enclosed by $S$ to apply Gauss' Divergence Theorem which means $S$ must include its flat top. However, in your final  line just below the surface $S$ being described seems to only be the cone without its flat top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can use the divergence theorem. You only have to compute the volume of the cone between $z=0$ and $z=1$. If you call it $E$, you have :

$$\int_E dx dy dz = 2\pi \int_0^1 \Big(\int_0^z r dr\Big)dz = \pi \int_0^1  z^2 dz = \frac{\pi}{3}$$

Therefore as $\text{div}(F(x,y,z))=3$ everywhere, you get that the flux is equal to $\pi$.

Comment: Yes, the flux over the cone with its flat top is $\pi$ which is equal to the flux over the flat top $z=1;x^2+y^2\leq 1$ alone. Therefore, the flux over the cone itself should be $0$.

Comment: @OliverKayende So to confirm, my calculation of the flux directly is correct, and the answer for divergence theorem is actually for the cone with an enclossed top? So should my answer actually be:

From what Arthur Breton commented:
$$ \iint_S F \cdot n dS = \iiint_E divFdV = (3)\iiint_EdV = (3)\left( \pi r^2\frac{h}{3}\right) = 3 \pi (1)^2 \frac{(1)}{3} = \pi$$

For the flat top, using $f(x,y) = z = 1$:
$$ \iint_S F \cdot n dS = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\langle 0,0,1\rangle \cdot \langle0,0,1\rangle rdrd\theta = \pi$$

And to get the sides of the cone, you subtract the two.

Comment: @Uberninja56. Yes.

Comment: You're missing the top disk, needed to apply the Divergence Theorem.